# rand() repeating values despite only one srand() call

Tags: c, loops, random, infinite

I have a function that generates x (parameter) random numbers, removes repeats, and returns the values stored in an array.

I am using rand() to call random numbers, however if I call the function with x parameter set to 5 it turns into an infinite loop as rand() continuously returns me the same 4 or 5 numbers.

I have only called srand() once in the main().

```
int main(void){
    srand(time(NULL));

    erase = eraser(4);
}

int* eraser(int array_size)
{
    array_size++;
    int* remove_ids = malloc(sizeof(int*) * array_size);
    int t, v;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++)    {
        t = 1+(rand() & 80);
        v = 1+(rand() & 80);

        printf("t=%d , v=%d\n", t, v);
        remove_ids[i] = t;

        if(i == 0){
            remove_ids[i] = array_size;
        }
        else {
            for(int c = 1; c < i; c++) {
                if(remove_ids[c] == t) {
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return(remove_ids);
}
```

Output:

```
t=1 , v=1
t=81 , v=1
t=81 , v=65
t=65 , v=17
t=17 , v=65
t=17 , v=65
t=1 , v=65
```

If I call `eraser(5)` I get stuck in an infinite loop.

Interestingly, on another function in the program rand() functions perfectly.

Comment: What do you think the `& 80` does?

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you!

Comment: Hint: `80 == 0x50 == binary 01010000`

Comment: `int* remove_ids = malloc(sizeof(int*) * array_size);` is not necessarily allocating the right size.  Use `int* remove_ids = malloc(sizeof *remove_ids * array_size);` and avoid mistakes.

Comment: @chux Thanks for the tip. Can you elaborate a little more on why the version you suggest is better? From my point of view, they seem the same.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(int*)` is the size of a pointer when the size of an `int` is needed here.  `sizeof *remove_ids` is the size of whatever `remove_ids` points to, which is the correct `int` here.  Using `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr *n);` idium is less likely to compute the wrong size. than `ptr = malloc(sizeof (I_hope_this_is_the_right_type) *n);`

Comment: `rand` isn't very random... you might already know this, but `rand` isn't safe for cryptographic / security purposes.

Comment: @chux Makes perfect sense. I will edit the code and keep that in min for the future. Much appreciated.

Comment: regarding: `srand(time(NULL));`  this will produce a compiler warning.  Suggest using: `srand( (unsigned int)time(NULL) );`   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want % (mod) instead of & (bitwise and).

Comment: Thanks. It was a pretty dumb mistake.